# how to use condition while using df.replace( to_replace = a dictionary with different columns and corresponding logic )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

for a given DataFrame:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame( data= { 'col1': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'col2': [100,450,550,2,4], 'col3':[-5,10,6,50,-4]  }  )

df1

      col1   col2   col3
    0   a    100    -5
    1   b    450    10
    2   c    550     6
    3   d      2    50
    4   e      4    -4
```

I can easily replace each  column with **respective** erroneous data with nan using `df.replace()` and dictionary like this:

```
toReplace_dictn = {   'col2' : [550,-99] , 'col3' : [-5,-99]   } 
df1.replace( to_replace= toReplace_dictn, value= np.nan )

col1    col2    col3
0   a   100.0   NaN
1   b   450.0   10.0
2   c   NaN     6.0
3   d   2.0     50.0
4   e   4.0     -4.0
```

However, I would like to use multiple condition for each columns, something like more than, greater than, etc. like this:

```
toReplace_dictn = {   'col2' : ( lambda x: x>=400 ) , 'col3' : ( lambda x: x<0 or x>=20 )   }
df1.replace( to_replace= toReplace_dictn, value= np.nan )
```

This doesn't work, it gives this error:

```
TypeError: Expecting 'to_replace' to be either a scalar, array-like, dict or None, got invalid type 'function'
```

I understand the error but is there some beautiful, concise, and elegant way using `df.replace` with dictionary that we can plug in **conditions** rather than single or list of values to replace?

Thanks in advance!

---

Probable solution:

I just figured out one approach. Also anyone is welcome to suggest more efficient way.

```
toReplace_dictn = {  'c2' : list( df1.loc[ (df1['c2']<0) | (df1['c2']>=400), 'c2' ] ) ,
                     'c3' : list( df1.loc[ (df1['c3']<0) | (df1['c3']>=20), 'c3' ] ),
                  }
```

and

```
df1.replace( to_replace= toReplace_dictn, value= np.nan )
```

Comment: We usually use loc assign ...which is elegant in my option as well

Comment: I just figured out one way (Beny are you also referring something like this?). Also anyone is welcome to suggest more efficient way.


toReplace_dictn = {  'c2' : list( df1.loc[ (df1['c2']<0) | (df1['c2']>=400), 'c2' ] ) ,
                     'c3' : list( df1.loc[ (df1['c3']<0) | (df1['c3']>=20), 'c3' ] ),
                  }

and 

df1.replace( to_replace= toReplace_dictn, value= np.nan )

Comment: df1.loc[ (df1['c2']<0) | (df1['c2']>=400), 'c2' ] = np.nan

Comment: @BENY - we would need multiple statements to modify multiple columns, can this be done in one statement?